# What is the role of human judgement given God's omnipotence and his plans

Tags: exegesis, free-will, evangelism

For example, some people view evangelism to be "most effective" using one method, whislt another person might view it as "most effective" to use another method. Ie, our opinions (and hence actions) can bring us closer/further away from God.

Another example would be differing views of the interpretation of the bible. Our opinions can be correct and hence bring us closer to God, or they can be incorrect and take us away from him.

To what extent can we rely on our own human judgement to help build a better relationship with God?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)  As it reads, this is asking for opinions, which Isn't within the scope of this site. For tips on how this could be salvaged,see [this](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/tips-for-editing-a-question-to-make-it-suitable-for-re-opening)

Comment: Your question is  pretty generalized, and would fit  better if asked about specific denomination as each denomination may have differing views on that subject. Please go to the help section and see how to ask questions, since the site has some particular formulas for asking questions on the site. Your questions will get better and quicker answers when properly presented, and it will save you feeling rejected when questions are voted down.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is a very good question.
The first thing to realize is that relationship is a two-way street.

When someone became a Christian, he or she began with accepting Christ. That's no work on our part, we just receive the Gift of Salvation.

Afterwards, the Holy Spirit is now living inside of this believer, preparing him or her to become God's temple. This is the critical point when the relationship between this believer and God began.  Two outcomes can result:

1. If the believer undergoes discipleship (as the Lord commanded in Matthew 28:19) that points him in the direction of submission to the authority of the Scripture and the Holy Spirit and he *took the time* to consume the Bible regularly without being critical, he will grow closer to God as the result. Which makes his judgement no longer relies on his own wisdom or intellects, but rather it will be more and more influenced by God's will in this person's life.
2. If the believer got stuck or distracted in the various ways (lack of discipleship, "instant-sunday-school"-recruitment, extreme dependence on liturgies, doctrinal debates, guilt-driven social works, became a celebrity, you name it). He remains distant from God and never acquire that growing relationship, because he is too busy *doing* his Christian actions rather than immerse himself in the Scriptures. Or he is so critical in his Bible reading.  In this case, his judgement is not Godly, is still of himself, and not only being useless for himself, but can also mislead others.

Therefore you see, our (human or self) judgement does not propel us closer to God by itself, only the Holy Spirit can do that.
Only when we submit to His authority, we can start reading the Bible with the right attitude, which will cause our judgement to be more God-powered, and less self-powered.

Last thought: God's plan is designed to be executed by God-powered Christians. It was not meant to be shouldered by self-powered individuals.

Hope this helps. And thank you for the excellent question.

Answer (score 0):

[**Proverbs 3:5-7**](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/proverbs/3/#v20003005)

> *"Trust in Jehovah with all your heart,
>   And do not rely on your own understanding.
>   6   In all your ways take notice of him,
>   And he will make your paths straight.
>   7   Do not become wise in your own eyes.
>   Fear Jehovah and turn away from bad."*

You can rely on God's judgement. Seek his understanding and it will be given to you.

[**Isaiah 55:9**](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/isaiah/55/#v23055009):

> *“For as the heavens are higher than the earth,
>   So my ways are higher than your ways
>   And my thoughts than your thoughts."*

In short we can't use our judgement to draw closer to God because our imperfect minds can't understand what God does. The only way we can draw closer to God is through reading his inspired word the bible and Praying to him.

[**Psalm 1:1-2**](http://wol.jw.org/en/wol/b/r1/lp-e/nwt/E/2013/19/1#h=3:0-7:0)

> *"Happy is the man who does not walk according to the advice of the wicked
>   And does not stand on the path of sinners
>   And does not sit in the seat of scoffers.
>    2 But his delight is in the law of Jehovah,
>   And he meditates on His law day and night."*

[**Philippians 4:6-7**](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/philippians/4/#v50004006)

> *"Do not be anxious over anything, but in everything by prayer and supplication along with thanksgiving, let your petitions be made known to God; 7  and the peace of God that surpasses all understanding will guard your hearts and your mental powers by means of Christ Jesus."*

Think of how you would draw closer to a friend. If you don't talk to that person and show no interest in what they want then they aren't really a friend are they? In that same way, to draw close to God we have to talk to him and get to know him.